# what's wrong with my data?

Tags: r, logistic, separation

Sorry,owing to my reputation,I have to delete the above word.
Originally I just want to copy this page's method,the author use titanic data to analyze relationship between fare and survivor.
And I finally know what's wrong with my data,my churn definition is daydiff>=180,but it is possible when daydiff>180 but he is not churner,so I test this guess with new variable lastdiff(mean the difference between last order and today) and I add some nonchurner on daydiff>=180 or churner on daydiff<=179,the warning message is gone.
this is the result:
[image]

author's page:
https://sites.google.com/site/rlearningsite/analysis/catagory/logit

Comment: What does a plot of `churner` against `daydiff` look like?

Comment: I never consider draw a plot...you can try it with my data

Comment: @jimmy, the folks here aren't around to do your analysis for you.  I think whuber is suggesting that you do this.  Doing so is a basic first step to any analysis and is something you should do anyway.

Comment: @jimmy what data are you deleting and why?

Comment: I delete the data based on unequal proportion of churner and nonchurner,churner is 98% in all data

Comment: What kind of plot should I draw? histogram?

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to know what is going on with your data, and as @StatsStudent points out, people here aren't going to do your analysis for you.  In the absence of more information, here are two wild guesses based on the fact that the estimate of your `(Intercept)` is `-42497` and the warning message is that "`...fitted probabilities numerically 0... occurred"`:

1. You have essentially no `0`'s in your `churner` variable, and
2. Your minimum `daydiff` value is very far from `0`.

Beyond those (somewhat educated) guesses, there is no way to know what is wrong with your data.

---

Upon trying to edit your post, I find it is still largely unintelligible, but did you define a `churner` as any observation where `daydiff` is $\ge 180$?  If so, you have induced complete separation into your dataset (in addition to doing something completely incoherent).  You can find out more my clicking on the tag I added.

Comment: is right and I actually looked at your data as well.  There is a complete separation of data points at >=180 of daydiff.

Comment: Hey gung,you mean the data should contain churner with daydiff<=179?,and what is the second message(minimum daydiff far from 0) ,thanks